# Same MySQL users on PHP site and Wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My website is built on PHP, can I add a sub domain using WordPress and the users be the same on both sites?

For example:

My current social network site is:
mysite .com

I want to add an eCommerce site to my current social networking site:
market.mysite .com

I want the users to only have to register one time, same profile info for both sites. Is this possible using MySQL users?

Comment: Yep, definitely possible.

Comment: What do you mean by mysql users? Mysql does not have any clue of the domain names you use as long as you have a single server.

Comment: do you really mean the same _Wordpress_ users rather than _mysql_ users? If your other site can access the WP database and read from the users tables reliably, then yes

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has its own users system, it doesn't create new mySQL users. You can use [WordPress multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) if you want to have the same user have rights on both sites if you want to switch the other site to WordPress. Otherwise you may be able to build a custom function that will allow a custom login that will log them in.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to share the same MYSQL user tables between two content management systems like wordpress and a cart engine. It would require some work by a web developer to achieve it.